# How to use AngularJS custom elements with jade?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, pug

I am having a problem were I cannot tell jade to render my custom elements of angularjs origin (directives), I want to know if there is any way to escape the tags so maybe at least they will be rendered as they are instead of going for the jade pre-processor, or maybe a way to tell jade to render my custom element somehow.

The current code looks like :

```
html
  head
    link(href='/main.css', rel='stylesheet')
    script(src='/lib.js')
    script(src='/main.js')
    title!= "Neuron@l"
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    link(rel="icon",href="/images/neuronal.png")
  body(ng-app="app",ng-view)
    "<top:bar></top:bar>"
    "<left:bar></left:bar>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem it's `top:bar` and `left:bar` here is the solution:

```
html
  head
    link(href='/main.css', rel='stylesheet')
    script(src='/lib.js')
    script(src='/main.js')
    title!= "Neuron@l"
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    link(rel="icon",href="/images/neuronal.png")
  body(ng-app="app",ng-view)
    top:bar
    left:bar
```

Comment: oh yes that solves it you are right, I had tried something similar but the error was somewhere else with angular removing the markup, thanks. At least this will now pop up in the results for someone else.